# Hadoop - Could not find or load main class TRUE

Tags: class, hadoop, installation, hdfs

When trying to test hadoop instalation it fails. with the folowing error:

```
`PS C:\hadoop-3.3.6> hdfs namenode -format
Error: Could not find or load main class TRUE`
```

What it can be?

Here is my core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.defaulterFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:900</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Here is my hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
    <value>C:\hadoop-3.3.6\data\namenode</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.name.dir</name>
    <value>C:\hadoop-3.3.6\data\datanode</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Here is my mapred-site.xml

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
    <value>yarn</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Here is my yarn-site.xml

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.auxservices.mapreduce.shuffle</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.shufflehandler</value>
  </property>

<!-- Site specific YARN configuration properties -->

</configuration>
```

Here is my hadoop-env.cmd

```
@echo off
@rem Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
@rem contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
@rem this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
@rem The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
@rem (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
@rem the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
@rem
@rem     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
@rem
@rem Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
@rem distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
@rem WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
@rem See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
@rem limitations under the License.

@rem Set Hadoop-specific environment variables here.

@rem The only required environment variable is JAVA_HOME.  All others are
@rem optional.  When running a distributed configuration it is best to
@rem set JAVA_HOME in this file, so that it is correctly defined on
@rem remote nodes.

@rem The java implementation to use.  Required.
set JAVA_HOME=C:\java\jdk-1.8

@rem The jsvc implementation to use. Jsvc is required to run secure datanodes.
@rem set JSVC_HOME=%JSVC_HOME%

@rem set HADOOP_CONF_DIR=

@rem Extra Java CLASSPATH elements.  Automatically insert capacity-scheduler.
if exist %HADOOP_HOME%\contrib\capacity-scheduler (
  if not defined HADOOP_CLASSPATH (
    set HADOOP_CLASSPATH=%HADOOP_HOME%\contrib\capacity-scheduler\*.jar
  ) else (
    set HADOOP_CLASSPATH=%HADOOP_CLASSPATH%;%HADOOP_HOME%\contrib\capacity-scheduler\*.jar
  )
)

@rem The maximum amount of heap to use, in MB. Default is 1000.
@rem set HADOOP_HEAPSIZE=
@rem set HADOOP_NAMENODE_INIT_HEAPSIZE=""

@rem Extra Java runtime options.  Empty by default.
@rem set HADOOP_OPTS=%HADOOP_OPTS% -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

@rem Command specific options appended to HADOOP_OPTS when specified
if not defined HADOOP_SECURITY_LOGGER (
  set HADOOP_SECURITY_LOGGER=INFO,RFAS
)
if not defined HDFS_AUDIT_LOGGER (
  set HDFS_AUDIT_LOGGER=INFO,NullAppender
)

set HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS=-Dhadoop.security.logger=%HADOOP_SECURITY_LOGGER% -Dhdfs.audit.logger=%HDFS_AUDIT_LOGGER% %HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS%
set HADOOP_DATANODE_OPTS=-Dhadoop.security.logger=ERROR,RFAS %HADOOP_DATANODE_OPTS%
set HADOOP_SECONDARYNAMENODE_OPTS=-Dhadoop.security.logger=%HADOOP_SECURITY_LOGGER% -Dhdfs.audit.logger=%HDFS_AUDIT_LOGGER% %HADOOP_SECONDARYNAMENODE_OPTS%

@rem The following applies to multiple commands (fs, dfs, fsck, distcp etc)
set HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS=-Xmx512m %HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS%
@rem set HADOOP_JAVA_PLATFORM_OPTS="-XX:-UsePerfData %HADOOP_JAVA_PLATFORM_OPTS%"

@rem On secure datanodes, user to run the datanode as after dropping privileges
set HADOOP_SECURE_DN_USER=%HADOOP_SECURE_DN_USER%

@rem Where log files are stored.  %HADOOP_HOME%/logs by default.
@rem set HADOOP_LOG_DIR=%HADOOP_LOG_DIR%\%USERNAME%

@rem Where log files are stored in the secure data environment.
set HADOOP_SECURE_DN_LOG_DIR=%HADOOP_LOG_DIR%\%HADOOP_HDFS_USER%

@rem
@rem Router-based HDFS Federation specific parameters
@rem Specify the JVM options to be used when starting the RBF Routers.
@rem These options will be appended to the options specified as HADOOP_OPTS
@rem and therefore may override any similar flags set in HADOOP_OPTS
@rem
@rem set HADOOP_DFSROUTER_OPTS=""
@rem

@rem The directory where pid files are stored. /tmp by default.
@rem NOTE: this should be set to a directory that can only be written to by 
@rem       the user that will run the hadoop daemons.  Otherwise there is the
@rem       potential for a symlink attack.
set HADOOP_PID_DIR=%HADOOP_PID_DIR%
set HADOOP_SECURE_DN_PID_DIR=%HADOOP_PID_DIR%

@rem A string representing this instance of hadoop. %USERNAME% by default.
set HADOOP_IDENT_STRING=%USERNAME%
```

I am using Hadoop 3.3.6. Is it problem in the configuration or I just missed something?

Can test the instalation with

```
hdfs namenode -format
```

Comment: Use cmd, not powershell to run the script

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a typo in your `core-site.xml`

It should be

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.defaulteFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:900</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

You wrote `fs.defaulterFS`

Comment: While true, the classloader runs before parsing the XML